# I cannot publish a service in port 8080 using Traefik

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I cannot publish my service in port 8080 even I redirect dasboard to another port, Traefik automatically redirect URL http://localhost:8080 to http://localhost:8080/dasboard. I need to publish in port 8080 because infrastructure out of my control.
Everything works fine if I use another port to publish my service.
My docker-compose file looks like:

```
version: "3.3"  
  services:
    traefik:
      image: "traefik:v2.8.1"
        command:
          - "--api.insecure=false"
          - "--providers.docker=true"
          - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
          -  "--entrypoints.traefik.address=:9090"
          - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
        ports:
          - "4000:9090"
          - "8080:80" # if I put another port it works fine
        volumes:
          - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    salamandra:
      image: "salamandra"
      container_name: "salamandra"
      ports:
        - "5000:8080"
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.salamandra.rule=Host(localhost)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.salamandra.entrypoints=web
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need that traefik service work on 8080

"--entryPoints.web.address=:8080"

and

"--entryPoints.traefik.address=:9090"

the dashboard listen on port 9090

https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/entrypoints/

Regards